# How to Deny Access to specific folder in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-5

I have one "Upload" folder in my project directory where I upload files & images. To get access to these files only by authorized access, I created a authorize Downloads Controller & provides files by that way. But if someone tried http://domain_name/Upload/filename.ext then that file accessible in browser. I want to restrict this Upload folder access to anonymous users. For this I tried:
http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/6/authorizing_folders_using_routeexistingfiles
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18218084/5756211
But nothing works for me. 
Thanks for the help in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While reading some security blog, I found one trick to do so.
I have added web.config file in Uploads folder & added following code-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The  will disallow all users from accessing from browser request, while its still accessible from code.

Comment: not working, I have a folder which contains .json file, added web.config but not working

Answer (score 1):

Use below code if someone could not able to find a solution for this issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
         <security>
             <authorization><add accessType="Deny" users="?"/></authorization>
         </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>'
```

Comment: How can we use this by allowing only users that have some role